# How to add a text+image+text+image+ ... in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using php for scripting. My typical problem is how do I add a question in mysql which has a lot of alternate text and images. Imagine something like a description from Organic Chemistry which has those benzene structures.

What's the most efficient way to do this? I understand that if I had a single image I can add an url to that image in the database.

Comment: You could look at MediaWiki as an example.

Comment: Store your question as HTML, upload the images into an upload directory to prepare relative links for `<img src=>` references.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be poor but i do it this way in my projects. You can create another table in your database.Let me explain this:

Text...Image...Text

You can handle this by this steps:

1. Create a table that will be post_meta
   Insert every image into this table and every image should have a post id
2. In the other table(actual post table) store your post something like this:
   Text...{MetaImage}....Text
3. When printing your post if you replace your tags with the image paths in the table post_meta, you could handle this.

By this way:
1. You will not store long and dirty image src's in the post table.
2. Your all media contents will be in a table.(image,music,video etc..)

Comment: thanks for the answer, how do you process {MetaImage Tag} when you find such a post? String processing?

Comment: There must be an engine, that replaces {MetaImage Tag} with the real value.